# Не корректно отображается дата создания поста Laravel

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь вывести в шаблоне дату создания поста `{{$blog->created_at->diffForHumans()}}`, дата выводится, но во всех постах одинаковая. А именно дата регистрации юзера, который пост запилил.

Такой контроллер

```
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::join('users','author_id','=','users.id')->find($id);

    if(!$blog) {
        return redirect()->route('post.index')->with('success', 'Ты дурак?');
    }
    return view('posts.blog_show', compact('blog'));
}
```

Я так понял поле `created_at` он у меня тянет с таблицы users, а как мне сделать, что бы тянуло с таблицы blogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при джойне одинаковые поля перезатираются.

То есть после запроса модель будет содержать данные обоих таблиц(toArray):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => first
    [author_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2010-02-02
    [name] => petya
)
```

поле created_at будет взято из присоединенной таблицы.

Самый простой способ решить проблему - явно указать какие поля нужны:

```
Blog::query()->select(['blogs.*', 'users.name'])->join('users','author_id','=','users.id')->find(1);
```

Тогда результат будет следующий(toArray):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => first
    [author_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2020-02-02
    [name] => petya
)
```

created_at - из таблицы blogs.

Этот способ не очень гибкий, так как каждый раз когда вам понадобиться новое поле пользователя, придется редактировать запрос.

---

Более верный способ - использовать [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Для этого нужно объявить связь в модели Blog:

```
public function author(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Запрос значительно упростится:

```
Blog::query()->with('author')->find(1)
```

Результат будет таким(toArray):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => first
    [author_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2020-02-02
    [author] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => petya
            [created_at] => 2010-02-02
        )

)
```

И никаких конфликтов имен не будет.